# Yii2 attributeLabels()

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have an ActiveRecord Model with this function for attribute labels:

```
public function attributeLabels() { 

        return  [
            'start_date' => Text::getText('model_group_StartDate'),
            // and many more texts ....
        ];
}
```

Now my problem is that when I use ActiveForm and let Yii load the labels automatically that it produces too many sql queries because everytime it loads a label it calls `attributeLabels()` and slows down my page.

I have to load the attribute labels from database.

I know that I can set own labels in ActiveForm via `label()` but I prefer having it in my model because I have to use the labels on different places.

I'm happy about any hints how to load the attribute labels only once.

Comment: If nothing either is there for localization you would like to use caching somehow. Have you read this [doc about caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html)? Esp. about the MemCache...

Comment: you can define *static* array of labels in attributeLabels() method and check it. If it's empty: initialize it with attribute labels from database, else just return it.

Comment: also can you tell us what `Text::getText()` actually does ?

Comment: Text::getText() fetches a text from database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii will indeed call your function `attributeLabels()` (and thus execute `Text::getText()`) every time an individual attribute label is requested.

You could solve this by caching the generated attribute labels on the *class* level, which means a label will only have to be generated once for each combination of {class, attribute} per request. If you have a common class that all of your ActiveRecord classes extend from, you can solve it once and for all with code like this:

```
class ActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    private static $getAttributeLabelCache;

    public function getAttributeLabel($attribute)
    {
        $class = get_class($this);

        if (!isset(self::$getAttributeLabelCache[$class][$attribute])) {
            self::$getAttributeLabelCache[$class][$attribute] = parent::getAttributeLabel($attribute);
        }

        return self::$getAttributeLabelCache[$class][$attribute];
    }
}
```

Somewhat related: https://github.com/laszlovl/yii2-staticactiverecord

Comment: Thanks! This works and reduces the database queries enormous.